# use variables inside php email

Tags: php, html, email

I am using google to generate my QR code from a random number.
this number is generated and then stored as a variable.
but I want to use it in a image link within an email.
Something like this, where $random is my variable:
Thanks

```
 $message = '<html>
               <head>
                  <title></title>
               </head>
               <body>
                 <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chld=L|1&chl=$random" />
               </body>
             </html>';
```

Comment: Guys!  Don't downvote a question just because it's easy.  A beginner doesn't know to use double quotes when including variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$message = '<html>
               <head>
                  <title></title>
               </head>
               <body>
                 <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chld=L|1&chl=' . $random . '" />
               </body>
             </html>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = 'Your text with ' . $random . ' string';
```

OR

```
$message = "Your text with $random string";
```

OR

```
$message = "Your text with <a href=\"$random\">string</a>";
```

I strongly suggest before you start programming read [basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) of chosen language.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$message = "<html>
           <head>
              <title></title>
           </head>
           <body>
             <img src=\"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chld=L|1&chl={$random} \" />
           </body>
         </html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = '<html>
               <head>
                  <title></title>
               </head>
               <body>
                 <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chld=L|1&chl=<?php echo $random; ?>" />
               </body>
             </html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Different quotes in PHP work in different ways. The single quote doesn't evaluate variables written directly in the string, so you have to close the quote and cat the variable with it: `echo 'variable: '.$variable.'.';`

Double quotes do evaluate variables inside the string though, so `echo "variable: $variable.";` would print the same as above.

You should use `$message = '...1&chl='.$random.'" />...';`